# Setting property in pivot table in many to many relation

Tags: relationship, vapor, vapor-fluent

I have set up a many to many relation Locale <-> Site via a pivot table `LocaleSite` in Vapor 4. This is working, I can attach `Locale` to `Site` and vice versa.
In the Pivot table, I added a property `.sortOrder`:

```
final class LocaleSite : Model {
    static let schema = "locale+site"
    
    struct FieldKeys {
        static var createdAt: FieldKey { "created_at" }
        static var updatedAt: FieldKey { "updated_at" }
        static var deletedAt: FieldKey { "deleted_at" }
        static var locale: FieldKey { "localeID" }
        static var site: FieldKey { "siteID" }
        static var sortOrder: FieldKey { "sortOrder" }
    }
    
    
    @ID
    var id: UUID?
    
    @Timestamp(key: FieldKeys.createdAt, on: .create)
    var createdAt: Date?

    @Timestamp(key: FieldKeys.updatedAt, on: .update)
    var updatedAt: Date?
    
    @Timestamp(key: FieldKeys.deletedAt, on: .delete)
    var deletedAt: Date?

    @Parent(key: FieldKeys.locale)
    var locale: Locale
    
    @Parent(key: FieldKeys.site)
    var site: Site
    
    @Field(key: FieldKeys.sortOrder)
    var sortOrder: Int
```

When attaching an array of Locales

```
for locale in locales {
    let _ = site.$locales.attach(locale, on: database)
}
```

I would like to set the `.sortOrder` to a certain value, in the same loop while attaching (maybe via the attach function?), but can **not find how** in the docs.

(The only workaround at the moment is after attaching is to query my site or locale, and via a relation to the pivot table setting the `.sortOrder`. Very inefficient...)

*Added code sample incorporating some of Calebs answer (See comment)*

```swift
static func createStdData (site: Site, database : Database) -> EventLoopFuture<Void> {
        return Locale.allLocale(database: database).map { locales in
            var order = 0
            for locale in locales {
                let _ = site.$locales.attach(locale, on: database, edit: { pivot in
                    pivot.sortOrder = order
                })
                order += 1
            }
        }
    }
```

As soon as the edit: is added I get the following error:

> No exact matches in call to instance method 'attach'

Checking the Vapor sources I see that there is one but apparently the syntax may not be completely right...

I also tried:

```swift
let _ = site.$locales.attach(locale, on: database, edit: (LocaleSite){ pivot in
                    pivot.sortOrder = order
                })
```

but the I get :

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What value you want to assign the `.sortOrder` property to will change how you will want to set that value. Based on your question I am going to assume that each pivot should have a `.sortOrder` that is `1` greater than the last.

To do this, we will first have to get the last pivot saved, before we start the loop. This is fairly straight forward:

```swift
let last = LocaleSite.query(on: database).sort(\.$sortOrder, .descending).first()
```

This query will order the results from highest `.sortOrder` to lowest, so the first one will have the highest value. We can now map that result. If we got a model back, we will base the new `.sortOrder` values off of it; otherwise, we'll just start from `0`.

```swift
let sortOrder = last.map { pivot in
    return pivot?.sortOrder ?? 0
}
```

Now we will call `.flatMap` on the result. In the `.flatMap` closure, we will iterate over the `Locale` models that you want to insert using `Array.map` and attach each `Locale` to the site. Now, the `.attach` method has [a handy closure](https://github.com/vapor/fluent-kit/blob/f0cc72ab101b88dfbdbe0b042da62386e1aa8195/Sources/FluentKit/Properties/Siblings.swift#L131) that you can pass in that you can use to edit the new pivot models before they are inserted into the database. We are going to use that closure to set the pivot's `.sortOrder` value.

```swift
sortOrder.flatMap { order in
    locales.enumerated().map { offset, locale in
        site.$locales.attach(locale, on: database, { pivot in 
            pivot.sortOrder = (order + 1) + offset
        })
    }.flatten(on: database.eventLoop)
}
```

<sub>* All code is written off the top of my head and untested, so it might need a touch up to get working properly</sub>

Comment: Great this is really helping me already a lot. Your implementation atm is a bit overkill as  for each new site added, there is a fresh 'sortOrder' so I can start with my local var order = 0 (but that part of your code will become handy in the future too I'm sure). However I'm running into a problem with the 'edit' closure that Xcode won't compile. Understandable as you wrote it off the top of your head, but can you have a quick look on what is the problem. I added my code to the original post.

Comment: @Glenn First off, you should really replace the `for-in` loop with `.map {}.flatten(on:)` to make sure the futures are handled correctly. As far as the compiler error, it looks like I missed that you don't use the `edit` parameter label. I've updated my answer to reflect that.